# YELP does not work right

Tags: yelp

When I click on DashHome then click on the questionmark, It brings up the help system. However when I enter a command to search on it tells me this does not exist. From what I understand the engine is YELP and is suppose to search everything including the man pages. However, I can't get it to find anything. I tried to install the yelp package but it tells me the one that is installed is the latest version. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Everything I read says hitting the F1 key is suppose to bring up yelp but 
Thanks in advance.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I think this is either a bug, or a mess up. Yelp is definitely able to bring up man pages if you start it from the terminal like this:

```
 yelp "man:ls"
```

Also, if you start yelp for example using F1, then choose Go -> all documents, and type *anything* in the search box, you will get an error. This [seems to be a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yelp/+bug/726439).